# Wizard form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a wizard form made in bootstrap,  i need to validate each step of the form wizard, how it is now is possible to go to the next step with empty inputs. And since there is quite a issue regarding bots, etc, what is the best way of validating each step on a form?

Here is the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        //Initialize tooltips
        $('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();
        
        //Wizard
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
    
            var $target = $(e.target);
        
            if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    
        $(".next-step").click(function (e) {
    
            var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
            $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
            nextTab($active);
    
        });
        $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {
    
            var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
            prevTab($active);
    
        });
    });
    
    function nextTab(elem) {
        $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
    }
    function prevTab(elem) {
        $(elem).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
    }
```

```css
    .wizard {
        margin: 20px auto;
        background: #fff;
    }
    
        .wizard .nav-tabs {
            position: relative;
            margin: 40px auto;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            border-bottom-color: #e0e0e0;
        }
    
        .wizard > div.wizard-inner {
            position: relative;
        }
    
    .connecting-line {
        height: 2px;
        background: #e0e0e0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
        color: #555555;
        cursor: default;
        border: 0;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }
    
    span.round-tab {
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        line-height: 70px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 100px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    span.round-tab i{
        color:#555555;
    }
    .wizard li.active span.round-tab {
        background: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #5bc0de;
        
    }
    .wizard li.active span.round-tab i{
        color: #5bc0de;
    }
    
    span.round-tab:hover {
        color: #333;
        border: 2px solid #333;
    }
    
    .wizard .nav-tabs > li {
        width: 25%;
    }
    
    .wizard li:after {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 46%;
        opacity: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        bottom: 0px;
        border: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
        transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .wizard li.active:after {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 46%;
        opacity: 1;
        margin: 0 auto;
        bottom: 0px;
        border: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
    }
    
    .wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        border-radius: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
        .wizard .nav-tabs > li a:hover {
            background: transparent;
        }
    
    .wizard .tab-pane {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .wizard h3 {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    
    @media( max-width : 585px ) {
    
        .wizard {
            width: 90%;
            height: auto !important;
        }
    
        span.round-tab {
            font-size: 16px;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
        }
    
        .wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
        }
    
        .wizard li.active:after {
            content: " ";
            position: absolute;
            left: 35%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <section>
            <div class="wizard">
                <div class="wizard-inner">
                    <div class="connecting-line"></div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    
                        <li role="presentation" class="active">
                            <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
                                <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
    
                        <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                            <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                                <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                            <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                                <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
    
                        <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                            <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Complete">
                                <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                            <h3>Step 1</h3>
                            <p>This is step 1</p>
                            <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
                            <h3>Step 2</h3>
                            <p>This is step 2</p>
                            <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3">
                            <h3>Step 3</h3>
                            <p>This is step 3</p>
                            <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-step">Skip</button></li>
                                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="complete">
                            <h3>Complete</h3>
                            <p>You have successfully completed all steps.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple but effective method for stopping a bot is called a honey spam pot. To implement this you can add an extra input at the end of your form and hide it within the css. Using PHP (advised for form validation!) you can check if that field is empty or not. If it is not empty then you know a bot has entered data into the input because a bot will try and avoid any validation by filling all the fields in. Validation in JavaScript or jQuery is more of a feature than a MUST use as it can be turned off by the user in their browser.

Comment: Check this resource for more information [link](http://jennamolby.com/how-to-prevent-form-spam-by-using-the-honeypot-technique/)